# Loan calculator with a dropdown box usingjavascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, calculator

Hi so i'm trying to make a loan calculator with a drop downbox. You enter in the amount you would like to borrow, then a dropdown appears with the interest rate at 6.75% or 9.71% . You then type over how many months you would like to repay your loan. However I have done everything i can think of and its not working? can anyone Please help me? thanks

this is the html

```
<body> 
<p>Loan Amount: €<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="1000000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>


<p>Interest Rate:
 <select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select A Loan Rate</option>
    <!-- 6.75 loan -->
    <option value="6.75" input id="interest_rate" onchange="computeLoan()">6.75%</option>
    <!-- 9.71 loan -->
    <option value="9.71" input id="interestRate" onchange="computeLoan()">9.75%</option>
</select>


<p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="60" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>


<h2 id="payment"></h2>
```

This is the javascript

```
// first function excute at a rate of 6.75% APR
function computeLoan()
{
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;

    var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;

    var months = document.getElementById('months').value;

    var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;

    var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);

    payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Your Monthly Payment = € "+payment;

}

// Second function excute at a rate of 9.71% APR

function computeLoan(){
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;

    var interestRate = document.getElementById('interestRate').value;

    var months = document.getElementById('months').value;

    var interest = (amount * (interestRate * .01)) / months;

    var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);

    payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

    document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Monthly Payment = $"+payment;
}
```

If anyone could help me on what to do it would be great! thank you

Comment: where is it breaking?  You arent really mentioning the issue you are running into?

Comment: Any errors?.......

Comment: when i run the code only one of the functions work, say if i comment out the second function, the first function will work and display the correct amount and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two functions that share the same name.

Create one function with conditional logic, that depends on the value of the select. I hope that helps!

Also, you should move the onchange attribute onto the select element instead of the option elements, and grab the value of the select.

Comment: can you explain "You should move the onchange attribute onto the select element instead of the option elements, and grab the value of the select." in a little further detail to what to do please? not 100% sure thanks

Comment: Something like this, 

<select id="rate" onchange="computeLoan()"> ...</select>

Then in your code, make the interest rate equal the value of the select. You can see an example [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I will give it a go thanks